# measure Time for two task

Tags: c#, .net, time, timespan, stopwatch

There are two task in my program ,I need to compute time for each task , I read about `stopwatch` and `TimeSpan` but I do not know which one must I use and how do that ,I want to measure time for each task in millisecond

```
for (int num = 2; num < 243; num++)
   {
     do something\\ compute time for first task
     do something\\ compute time for second task

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) for this

```
 Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

  watch.Start();

  // do something
  watch.Stop();

  Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  watch.Reset();

  watch.Start();
  // do something different
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
//code to measure
var timeTaken = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Give your explanation also.